# how to show pdf files in .apk using phonegap+html+javascript

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a html website and would like to use phonegap build to convert to an Android native app. I am trying to use inappbrowser to open the pdf from a link.

My zip contains:
index.html
config.xml
"pdf" (folder that contain pdfs)

index.html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('pdf/test.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes')";>TESTTEST</a>
```

config.xml:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
   <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

I am using phonegap 3.3 and testing on Samsung Galaxy s2, however the link doesn't do anything. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: pls confirm this value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" in config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Android's inAppBrowser does not have a pdf viewer so you will not be  to show the pdf.  Look at the answer here (http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/inappbrowser_not_loading_pdf_on_android) for how to display a pdf.

Comment: thank you! But I need to display a pdf in android_asset and looks like the only way is to first move my pdf files to somewhere on Android SD storage before displaying the pdfs.

Comment: Yes I believe this is the only way you could do it.  You could have a link that downloads them off of your server.  You might be able to convert the pdfs to an image or an html page.